# Does the dart pdf library support TextInput to generate PDF as interactive form?

Tags: dart-pdf

I need in flutter to dynamically create a PDF that will contains some TextInput so that the generated PDF is like a PDF interactive form and the end user can fill the textbox.

Does the library support the interactive PDF form components TextBox CheckBox ?

Thanks

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/working-with-forms

Comment: Sorry but syncfusion is commercial library. Question is related dart-pdf library.